# Change Yii Custom form validator error message {attribute}

Tags: yii

I can change form validator error message by these code in my model:

```
array('name, email, subject, body', 'required'
                        'message'=>'Please enter a value for {attribute}.'),
```

but i don't know where the {attribute} came from and how can i change it for each field, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these :

```
return array(
    // name, email, subject and body are required
    array('name', 'required',
                'message'=>'Please enter a value for name.'),
    array('email', 'required',
                'message'=>'Please enter a value for email.'),
    array('subject', 'required',
                'message'=>'Please enter a value for subject.'),
    array('body', 'required',
                'message'=>'Please enter a value for body.'),
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if i understand your question right, but you asked where the `{attribute}` came from:

Some validators introduce placeholders like the `{attribute}` in your example. If validation fails, they will be replaced with the attribute name. So if no `name` was entered and your `message` is `'Please enter a valid {attribute}.'` the error message will be "*Please enter a valid name*".

While the `{attribute}` placeholder can be used with every validator, some of them introduce even more placeholders. For example with the [`CStringValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator) you can use `{min}`, `{max}` or `{length}`. They will be replace with the number of *minimum*, *maximum* or *exact* characters respecitvely.

Here's an example:

```
array('firstname,lastname', 'string', 'min'=>3, 
    'tooShort'=>'Your {attribute} must contain at least {min} letters.'
),
```

This will give "*Your firstname must contain at least 3 letters.*" if the users enters less than 3 letters. This has the advantage that if you change the `min` parameter, your message will automatically be updated. So it's less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

The `{attribute}` is taken from your function:

```
    public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'email' => 'Email',

    );
}
```

on your model.